# Can't run jupyter notebook in docker installation of tensorflow-gpu-jupyter

Tags: nvidia, docker, jupyter

I followed instructions from here to install a tensorflow docker image: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

I pulled the image with this command `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter` to install jupyter enabled image.

When I run the image with `sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter` , I get this: `To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-9-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://(acc54e047054 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=26646d53421996f1ec27c65ca1bbeabb0fd8fadb2f7303e2`

However I cannot access the notebook at either of these urls using chrome.

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Any error message in the console or in the browser?

You can try to run a bash with the *-it* parameter an `/bin/bash` at the end. Then run jupyter manually from inside the container with `jupyter notebook --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --no-browser` .

Perhaps this give you some message or something.